# How to prove that the ring of upper trianglular matrices is not semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

I was wondering how to prove that the ring 
$$R= \bigg\{ 
  \
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & c \\
  \end{array} } \right): \
  a,b,c \in \mathbb{C} \ \bigg\} 
$$ 
is not semisimple. One way that i followed is considering the exact sequence
$$
0 \to U \to V \to V/U \to 0 
$$ where 
$$U=\bigg\{ 
  \
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a \\
   0 \\
  \end{array} } \right): \
  a \in \mathbb{C} \ \bigg\} \text{ and }
V= \bigg\{ 
  \
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
    a \\
    b \\
  \end{array} } \right): \
  a,b \in \mathbb{C} \ \bigg\} 
$$
with purpose to prove that is not splitting. In this case, i can't find any function $f: V/U \to V$ or an other argument to get the result.

Comment: That argument works perfectly. You can also show that the Jacobson radical is not zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fine.

For another thing, $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\middle|\,b\in\mathbb C\right\}$ is a nonzero nilpotent ideal.

Yet another way: because of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, the only possible $3$ dimensional semisimple $\mathbb C$ algebra is $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$, which is commutative, and this isn't.